# Como rellenar el array de otra forma?

Tags: javascript

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  
  // Para uso
  var matriz = [];
  var i = 0;
  
  for (i; i<=50; ++i) {
    
    matriz.push(i);
    
  }
  
  matriz.forEach(function(e) {
    
    document.write(e + '\n');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

*Realizo un `for` para rellenar el `array` con 50 numeros y así luego mostrar por pantalla todo el `array` con `forEach`, pero como podría rellenar el array sin bucles?(pero **si usar** el `forEach` para mostrar los números)*

Comment: var matriz = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.........,50];  XD

Comment: var i = 0;
  
  for (i; i<=50; ++i) {
    
    document.write(i + '\n');
    
  }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si los números tienen que ser consecutivos podrías hacer algo así:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  
  // Para uso
  var matriz = Array.apply(null, {length: 50}).map(Number.call, Number);
  
  matriz.forEach(function(e) {
    
    document.write(e + '\n');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

El constructor del objeto Array básicamente lo que hace es (el código está simplificado para que se entienda mejor):

```
function Array() {
  var a = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     a.push(arguments[i]);
  }
  return a;
}
```

Al pasarle al apply un objeto con una propiedad length igual a la longitud deseada (50) en lugar de un array de argumentos lo que conseguimos es:

```
function Array() {
  var a = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
     a.push(undefined);
  }
  return a;
}
```

Lo que crea un Array de 50 posiciones con todos sus valores inicializados como `undefined`.

La llamada al método `map` provoca que se llame a la función de callback pasada como argumento (en nuestro caso `Number.call`) una vez por cada elemento del array pasándole 3 argumentos: el valor actual del elemento, el índice o posición dentro del array y el propio array.

Es decir, por ejemplo para el elemento de la 5ª posición del array (índice 4) la llamada será:

```
Number.call(undefined, 4, [0,1,2,3,undefined,undefined,....]);
```

Lo que vendría a ser equivalente a llamar a:

```
Number(4) // Que va a devolver 4
```

Comment: Podrias explicar un poco como funciona, y porque funciona?

Comment: Podrias explicar por que funciona? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n para los que sepan ingles. :)

Comment: He editado la respuesta para incluir una explicación bastante más resumida. Omito ciertos detalles pero creo que se puede entender mejor.

Answer (score 3):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente para crear un arreglo de 50 elementos con números consecutivos

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

  var matriz = Array(50).fill().map(Number.call, Number);

  matriz.forEach(function(e) {
    document.write(e + '\n');
  });

});
```